# Does the MtG lore have an official explanation for banned cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-lore

(Specifically, those *other than*: [ante cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+%5B%22for%20ante%22%5D), [un-cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?format=%5B%22Un-Sets%22%5D), [Shahrazad](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shahrazad).)

I remember reading someone speculating that knowledge of how to cast them was mostly lost, with those who still know generally unwilling to teach others. What's the in-universe story behind banned cards, if there is one?

Comment: Per [this meta question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1056/13741), I believe my question is acceptable here. ​ In any case, I'm not aware of any other site which would accept it. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: In any case, it's a very vague question. If you could provide any source at all for that speculation, that might be helpful.

Comment: I don't think there's even a flavor explanation for the formats themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, none of the media put out by Wizards of the Coast provides thematic justification for the banning, or restriction, of specific cards. In a general sense, some keyword abilities or effects only appear in specific regions, because they are generated thematically for those portions of the verse.

Cards are banned solely for mechanical reasons, to limit the dominance they would exercise within one format or another. The intent is to avoid tournaments where the banned cards start to define the meta, to the extent that there is only one deck played, or one deck and a deck designed to beat it.

That is specifically highlighted by Wizards of the Coast on the

> **[Banned and Restricted Lists](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/bannedrestricted)**
>   One key to the continued health of Magic is diversity. It is vitally important to ensure that there are multiple competitive decks for the tournament player to choose from. Why? If there were only a single viable deck to play, tournaments would quickly stagnate as players were forced to either play that deck or a deck built specifically to beat it. In addition, different players enjoy playing different types of decks. If there are plenty of viable options to play, there will be more players at more tournaments.
>   To help maintain the diversity and health of the Magic tournament environment, a system of banned and restricted lists has been developed. These lists are made up of cards that are either not allowed at all, or allowed only in a very limited manner.
>   It’s important to note a couple of things: First, these lists apply only to Constructed formats and not Limited formats. Second, the banned and restricted lists are format-specific, so a card that is banned in Modern may still be legal to play in Standard.
>   Banning a card is uncommon. Announcements for changes to the Banned & Restricted lists are done all together on the Monday after a new set’s Prerelease, to go into effect with that set’s release. This way, the formats you play change as infrequently as possible.

For specific guidance on why a card was banned, you would have to look through the Magic the Gathering Article Archives for [Banned and Restricted Announcement](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/september-28-2015-banned-and-restricted-announcement-2015-09-28)'s. Googling with the terms "banned", "restricted", "announcement", and *card name* will get you the pertinent announcement.

Comment: I think his question was, what is the "in-universe" justification for no longer being able to "cast those spells" as it were

Comment: @RobertWertz Well, I look like a putz. As an avid reader of the scene setting books and content made available by Wizards, there isn't an answer to that question. The banning or restricting of cards is solely a mechanical response to the dominance those cards have on tournament play.

Comment: That was what I figured, sadly. Maybe that's the next story they should write! Unrelated, I've been trying to get all that content and haven't really found it anywhere. Any suggestions for where to go (other than Uncharted Realms) to get all their fiction?

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_novels) has a list of all of the MTG novels. I think that along with Uncharted Realms and card flavor text, the novels are the primary source of lore.

Comment: (I'll accept this once it's at least 48 hours old if still at that point [no one has given evidence otherwise] and [no one has claimed that they will give such evidence in a reasonable amount of time].) ​ ​

Comment: @RobertWertz Do you realize how difficult it would be to try and write something about this kind of thing?

Comment: @Waterseas Writing it in terms of an answer, or a lore justification?

Comment: Drunk, I think he meant lore justification. It would be difficult to tell an interesting story of spells becoming not used anymore or of people dying off and losing their cultural memory or whatever. @murgatroid99 thanks! I had found general lists but not with ISBN like that, much appreciated.

Comment: I can't see what the lore justification *could* be, since you'd also be having to introduce the idea of formats into Magic lore (not all cards are banned in all formats). Unless the lore takes a hard left into "Yu-Gi-Oh" style battles, I don't think this will ever come up. :)